# Cannot initialise gstreamer pipeline

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

[System Info:]

- Ubuntu 16.04 in a Virtualbox
- Kernel: Linux 4.13.0-36-generic
- Architecture: x86-64
- ROS kinetic

I am trying to follow the audio common installation and ran into the problem mentioned here
https://answers.ros.org/question/286550/no-element-or-plugin-alsasrc/
i now installed

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-alsa
```

And the pipeline seemed to work properly:

```
gst-launch-1.0 alsasrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! alsasink

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstAudioSrcClock
Redistribute latency...
Redistribute latency...
^Chandling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
Execution ended after 0:00:12.309985956
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
```

But I cant hear any sound from my mic...
Anyone here, who has a hint how to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286566/cannot-initialise-gstreamer-pipeline/) by [nina-lg](https://answers.ros.org/users/34315/nina-lg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2018-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved it myself!

```
gst-launch-1.0 alsasrc ! alsasink sync=false
```

worked fine!

---

Originally posted by [nina-lg](https://answers.ros.org/users/34315/nina-lg/) with karma: 76 on 2018-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-27**:
Is there any trade-off when setting `syn=false`? Is there a fundamental necessity to set `sync=false` in some cases? Or is this something that became necessary with the new gstreamer release?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-27**:
And more importantly: should the tutorial you linked in #q286550 be updated?

**Comment by [Rohan0993](https://answers.ros.org/users/39160/rohan0993/) on 2018-12-24**:
Shouldn't there be an explaination on why it worked fine?

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-10-03**:
fixed it for me as well